# Emacs 24 with fullscreen?

Tags: fullscreen, emacs

Is there a way to use Emacs 24 in fullscreen mode? The [Emacs wiki](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/FullScreen#toc22) seems to imply that it has been disabled, but that there are some workarounds / patches.

It doesn't have to be "true" full screen, but I like to work without having the OS menubar  on the top and launcher at the bottom.

In the end, it is not clear how I can implement these patches or workarounds, which one I should use and / or if I should just install emacs <= 23.3.

My current .emacs includes the following (which allows me to use F11 to toggle fullscreen under Emacs 23 in Linux)

```
(defun fullscreen ()
 (interactive)
 (set-frame-parameter nil 'fullscreen
              (if (frame-parameter nil 'fullscreen) nil 'fullboth))
(progn
  (if (fboundp 'tool-bar-mode) (tool-bar-mode -1))  ;; no toolbar
  (menu-bar-mode -1) ;;no menubar
  (scroll-bar-mode -1) ;; no scroll bar
  )
)

(global-set-key [f11] 'fullscreen)
```

Comment: They also say [here](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/FullScreen#toc22) that it works with the Aquamacs and CarbonEmacs projects, but the one deprecated linked to below seems like maybe the best choice. Also, to get rid of the 'launcher' if you're talking about the built-in OS X 'Dock' just hit command-option-d and it will go into 'hidden' mode whereby only moving your mouse to the very bottom edge of the screen will bring it up. Hit the same key combination to reverse.

Answer (score 2):

If you use Yamamoto Mitsuharu's [emacs-mac-port](https://github.com/railwaycat/emacs-mac-port) then true full-screen "Just Works" (and much else too).  No need for any patches or workarounds.  At least, this is true for me on Mountain Lion.  YMMV on earlier OS versions.

Comment: works much better than emacsformacosx port, which puts up the wretched toolbar (even if you have toolbar set OFF), and then messes up the window if you interactively turn the toolbar off again.